# How do you divide a single column in a table by a constant in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

Sorry if this seems trivial, but I am fairly new to Tableau. I have a simple table that has 1 dimension for columns and 1 dimension for rows. My Marks are the Count of a third dimension. I'd like to divide only 1 of the columns in the table by a constant but not all of them. When I have tried conditional statements, I receive the error regarding mix of non-aggregate and aggregate statements.

What is the best way to divide a single column's values based upon a condition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the error regarding non-aggregate and aggregate statements can be resolved using the ATTR() function.

```
SUM([Sales]) / [Constant]
```

Turns to:

```
SUM([Sales]) / ATTR([Constant])
```

Or conversely, which might or might not fit your data:

```
[Sales] / [Constant]
```

You just cant mix the two as in the first example.

**Edit**

This is probably a more accurate place for the ATTR() function given what I'm guessing is your use case:

```
If ATTR([Segment]) = 'Corporate'
Then COUNT(Sales) / SUM([Constant])
END
```

Comment: If the above is not similar to your calculated field, then it may be beneficial for you to post a calculated field made on a view similar to yours built in the default Tableau Superstore dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the constant to a discrete measure and see if that works. (right-click on measure and select 'discrete')

Answer (score 0):

Also, without seeing the conditional code you are using, you probably need to wrap the entire condition with count() in order to not get the Aggregate/Non-Aggregate error, like this:

```
Count(If [MyDimension] = "XX" then [MyOtherDimension] else Null End)
```

NOT like this:

```
If [MyDimension] = "XX" then Count([MyOtherDimension]) else Null End
```